# How to color the 3D models through a web application using Autodesk Forge APIs?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, autodesk-forge, revit-api

We are building a web application to browse/view 3D models.We are using the Forge APIs to view the models in web browser. We wanted to make the colors changed based on the user inputs. Please help us suggesting the API that needs to be used for coloring the models.

Comment: Questions here are usually more answerable if you can show what you have tried, and/or the research you have done. If you have not tried any code or done any research, then it is likely that it is too early for you to ask a question. In other words, it will help you be as self-directed as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use our Viewer technology with one of the functions that is available for changing material color on parts of the model.

Check out this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/happy-easter-setthemingcolor-model-material